# Create non clustered indexes in background without awaiting the outcome in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, index, azure-sql-database, migration

I have to release a new version of an application. I created two scripts one to move the schema and one to migrate the data. The script contains a long list of queries.

The application needs to stay offline as little as possible, for this reason, I'd like to make this script run faster.

I noted that the biggest slowdown is in the non-cluster index creation in some tables. Is it possible to trigger the creation of the indexes and in the meanwhile continue the execution of the script?

I know it is possible to create `WITH (ONLINE = ON)` to avoid locking the table, but I'm interested in understanding if it is possible to run the queries in the script asynchronously so that the time to execute is not sequential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to break down your script into multiple scripts/queries:

1. Script does something
2. Non-clustered index creation
3. Script continues to do something

Then the solution would be to use more than one session to do the work:

Your app creates a session, runs step 1.
When step 1 is completed, your app needs to span another session in parallel, and run step 2 (index creation) in that session. In the meantime, first session can continue with step 3, while second session runs step 2 (index creation) in the background.

This will work with permanent tables, or global temp tables. This won't work with regular temp tables